# Aggregate by custom time windows in Kusto KQL Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to aggregate metric values in specific time windows provided by another table (which captures when a test was executed).

```
let TestTimes = datatable (start:datetime, end:datetime, testId:string)
[
 datetime(2022-09-15T09:29-4), datetime(2022-09-15T13:10-4), "test1",
 datetime(2022-09-15T17:51-4), datetime(2022-09-15T22:12-4), "test2",
 datetime(2022-09-20T10:50-4), datetime(2022-09-20T15:10-4), "test3",
 datetime(2022-09-21T09:00-4), datetime(2022-09-21T14:20-4), "test4",
 datetime(2022-09-21T16:00-4), datetime(2022-09-21T20:00-4), "test5",
 . . .
];
```

I create a simple function that accepts a metric table and start/end times

```
let CountMetric = (T:(Timestamp:datetime, Name:string),startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime, metricName:string) {
  T 
  | where Timestamp between(startTime..endTime)        
  | where Name == metricName
  | summarize count = count()
};
```

I can call the function in isolation:

```
CountMetric(MyMetricsTable, datetime(2022-09-15T09:29-4), datetime(2022-09-15T13:10-4), "Metric1");
```

But, I cannot call it in the context of a query such as running it on the test times table rows:

```
TestTimes
| extend Metric1Counts = CountMetric(MyMetricsTable, start, end, "Metric1")
```

The error I get is:
Tabular expression is not expected in the current context

Any idea how to solve this simple problem?

Comment: Please change this post topic. The current one has nothing to do with your actual question.

Comment: Kind reminder to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

That required some acrobatics...

```
let MyMetricsTable = // data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
    materialize
    (
        range i from 1 to 10000 step 1
        | extend Timestamp = datetime(2022-09-10) + 15d*rand()
                ,Name = strcat("Metric", tostring(toint(rand(3) + 1)))
    );
let TestTimes = datatable (start:datetime, end:datetime, testId:string)
    [
        datetime(2022-09-15T09:29:00-04), datetime(2022-09-15T13:10:00-04), "test1"
       ,datetime(2022-09-15T17:51:00-04), datetime(2022-09-15T22:12:00-04), "test2"
       ,datetime(2022-09-20T10:50:00-04), datetime(2022-09-20T15:10:00-04), "test3"
       ,datetime(2022-09-21T09:00:00-04), datetime(2022-09-21T14:20:00-04), "test4"
       ,datetime(2022-09-21T16:00:00-04), datetime(2022-09-21T20:00:00-04), "test5"
    ];
let CountMetric = (T:(Timestamp:datetime, Name:string),startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime, metricName:string)
    {
    T 
    | where Timestamp between(startTime..endTime)        
    | where Name == metricName
    | summarize count = count()
    }; 
let CountMetricWrapper = (T:(start:datetime, end:datetime, testId:string), metricsTableName:string, metricName:string)
{
    let p_start  = toscalar(T | project start);
    let p_end    = toscalar(T | project end);
    let p_testId = toscalar(T | project testId);
    CountMetric(table(metricsTableName), p_start, p_end, metricName)
    | extend testId = p_testId
};
let TestTimesSerialized =
materialize
(
    TestTimes
    | serialize
    | extend params_batch_id  = row_number(0) / 64 + 1
            ,params_set_id    = row_number(0) % 64 + 1
);  
union  // Each line supports additional 64 parameters sets
    (TestTimesSerialized | where params_batch_id == 1 | partition hint.strategy=legacy by params_set_id (invoke CountMetricWrapper("MyMetricsTable", "Metric1")))
   ,(TestTimesSerialized | where params_batch_id == 2 | partition hint.strategy=legacy by params_set_id (invoke CountMetricWrapper("MyMetricsTable", "Metric1")))
   ,(TestTimesSerialized | where params_batch_id == 3 | partition hint.strategy=legacy by params_set_id (invoke CountMetricWrapper("MyMetricsTable", "Metric1")))
```

| count | testId |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | test1 |
| 33 | test5 |
| 51 | test4 |
| 44 | test2 |
| 45 | test3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=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)